# powershell function treats nested object (each of them with one row) as one object

Tags: function, powershell, nested, powershell-3.0

I have something like this now (Powershell v3):

Function (saved as file):

```
function global:Send-MailWithFormattedTables{
param(
[Parameter(
    Mandatory = $true,
    ValueFromPipeline = $true)] [object[]]$Objects
    #..and other parameters
)
Foreach ($object in $Objects){
    #each object is enumerated
}
```

and the script:

```
C:\tools\Scripts\functions\Send-MailWithFormattedTables.ps1
$Parameters = @{
    objects = $object1, $object2 
}
Send-MailWithFormattedTables @Parameters
```

Sometimes it will be ONE OBJECT (this is important in this case) or more than two objects. There are plenty of other parameters but it doesn't matter now.
It all works just fine but ONLY where each object has MORE THAN 1 row.
When this happens function treats two objects as one object (joining two separate rows to one object) and **enumerating each row instead of each object**.
I tried:

```
$Parameters = @{
    objects = [object]$object1, [object]$object2
    #..and other parameters
}
```

without positive effect.
It's all fine when I executing code without using function (even when both objects has only one row):

```
$Objects = $object1, $object2
Foreach ($object in $Tables){
    #each object is enumerated
}
```

How can I prevent this behavior?

*BTW - function is called with any numer of object and puts them to email as html separate tables. each of these tables has unique titles.
It looks like this (without using function - with two objects each with one row):*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYQzB.jpg

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried explicitly declaring $object1 and $object2 as arrays? Like `$object1 = @(value)`

Comment: Sounds like you need to fully format your function with Begin/Process/End to setup the mail in the Begin, add objects as content in the Process, and send it in the End. Also, you probably want to define it as [Array]$Objects because you want an array of objects to be able to parse through.

Comment: I tried to avoid this scenario. I'll have to try it. I'll write, whether it's helped me.